# c++ 11 =default keyword on virtual function for specifying default pure implementation

Tags: c++11, default, keyword, pure-virtual

I am curious why, in C++ 11, use of "= default" on a derived virtual method does not select the pure base class implementation.

For example, the following test code produces the message "error: 'virtual void B::tst()' cannot be defaulted" from "g++ -std=c++11".

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A () = default;
  virtual void tst () = 0;
};

void A :: tst () {}

struct B : public A {
  virtual void tst () = default;
};
```

We can of course provide a B::tst that invokes the default base implementation, but one is concerned that this might be the higher overhead implementation compared to a hypothetical "= default" based coding.

Sorry to ask questions about what might or might not be within the minds of the c++ standards committee persons, but nevertheless perhaps someone here at stack overflow will have some wisdom concerning the impracticality of using the default keyword in this way that would be interesting to hear.

Thanks!

Comment: By default a child class shares the parent's implementation without writing anything, assuming the child inherits from the parent non-privately.  So, in this context, what are you trying to have `= default` mean?

Comment: When the virtual function is pure we require that the derived class chooses an implementation. The derived class can provide an implementation or choose to call a default implementation in the base. However the = default could potentially allow the derived to specify the base default just be loaded into the vtable by the compiler, which would be potentially more efficient compared to dispatching to a derived implementation that turns around and calls back to the default base implementation. I do however consider it an important design choice to make the derived class choose at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard *§8.4.2/p1 Explicitly-defaulted functions [dcl.fct.def.default]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> A function definition of the form:
>
> `attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt declarator
>   virt-specifier-seqopt = default;`
>
> is called an explicitly-defaulted definition. A function that is
>   explicitly defaulted shall
>
> (1.1) — **be a special member function,**
>
> (1.2) — have the same declared function type (except for possibly differing ref-qualifiers and except that in
>   the case of a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be “reference to
>   non-const T”, where T is the name of the member function’s class) as if it had been implicitly declared,
>   and
>
> (1.3) — not have default arguments

Member function `tst()` is not a [special member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions). Thus, it cannot be defaulted.

Now specifying a member function of a class (e.g., `class A`) as pure virtual entails that any class that inherits from that class and you don't wan't it to be abstract as well must override that member function.

Comment: ok, the standard says that this type of pure base class default implementation selecting behavior isnt supported, but nevertheless one is curious why it isnt